# When does a stationary distribution for a CTMC not exist?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process

Recalling that a Continuous-time Markov Chain (CTMC) is defined by its generator matrix $Q$, when does a stationary distribution for a CTMC not exist? Or when does there not exist a probability vector $\pi$ s.t. $\pi Q = 0$? If there is a mathematical reason, is there also a statistical interpretation? Thanks!

(The difficulty seems to lie in the fact that $\pi$ must also be a probability vector. For example, a vector of ones is a clear right eigenvector with eigenvalue $0$, which implies that $Q$ must also have at least one left eigenvector with eigenvalue $0$. But when can it be scaled to be a probability vector? As an additional note, for discrete Markov Chains we have Perron-Frobenius, which helps guarantee the existence of a stationary distribution.) (Edited 12:20 PM EST, 4/1/2021)

Comment: This explains it pretty nicely. https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter11/11_3_2_stationary_and_limiting_distributions.php

Comment: @mlofton Maybe the question was worded incorrectly, but like beyond the basic definition of the stationary distribution, when does the stationary distribution not exist? I also edited the question above to add a bit more of my thoughts in case that is helpful.

Comment: Hi: If you write your question ( but without the acronym ) in google, one of the results will be a pdf at mast.queensu.ca. In that document, there is a section titled "existence and uniqueness". It seems that the requirements for existence are that the markov chain has to be irreducible and recurrent but obviously there are many more details dicsussed.  I think that section should explain it but of course it will take some time to go through it. If that doesn't do it, then I would get one of the theory books on markov chains. Norris's  "Markov Chains" probably covers your question.

Comment: @mlofton Are you referring to https://mast.queensu.ca/~stat455/lecturenotes/set5.pdf ? If so, then unfortunately it mainly talks about the existence for the limiting distribution of the CTMC and implicitly assumes that the stationary distribution already exists. The book reference is definitely helpful -- definitely worth checking out! Thanks!

Comment: @mlofton (Evidently, a limiting distribution is a stationary distribution, although the space of generators such that it has a stationary distribution may be larger, as it is not an iff statement.)

Comment: I'm sorry nanko. I was talking about set3.pdf at the same link.  My apologies for the confusion.